# iOS Image upload to S3 by using Node.js with Multiparty and GraphicsMagick

Tags: ios, node.js, amazon-s3, graphicsmagick, ng-file-upload

We have a website which is using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to send request to backend to upload images. It converts image into different sizes and upload to Amazon S3 server. It is working fine on web. Our front-end and back-end contains JS code.

From iOS App, we can upload files to [AWS SDK for iOS](http://sledgedev.com/aws-s3-image-upload-using-aws-sdk-for-ios-v2/), but it's taking too much time as well request timed out all time.

As per requirement, by using conventional method for file uploading from iOS App to **server (Node)**, then converting to different sizes **(ng-file-upload - multiparty & GraphicsMagick)** & then upload to **Amazon server (S3)**.

So, we're using traditional method to upload image to backend server.

**Code for Image Upload**

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                           requestWithURL:url
                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                           timeoutInterval:DEFAULT_TIMEOUT];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831464368775746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[urlRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//Image
if(imageData)
{
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", imgName, imgName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [body appendData:imageData];
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];
```

We're using **multiparty** in node.js backend. Even we're unable to get any files object to populate for further steps. It throws an error in backend.

File details in **Request headers** are empty in backend while uploading from application. So, we get an error like **'path' undefined**.

So, we're not getting any file or image to backend, so cannot process further for conversation as well upload. We stuck at this place.

Comment: Please verify once at server (Node) script filename must be same as sending from iOS

Comment: and from ios we are using like that to upload image on server.  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"
; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", imgName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: @sandy Thank you so much mate.. You saved my day!! Cheers :)

Comment: @sandy update it in answer..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must have to follow two steps -

**1-** Please verify once at server (Node) script filename must be same as sending from iOS.

**2-** from ios we are using like that to upload image on server.

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\" ; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", imgName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**name=\"userfile\"** must be match with server script.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I made mistake by passing name value..:)